# Check if username or password true or false with jquery using web services

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, web-services

here is mine C# code

```
public void Login(string kullaniciAd, string sifre)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=twitter;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblKullanici WHERE kullaniciAdi = @kullaniciAd or sifre = @kullaniciSifre", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kullaniciAd", kullaniciAd);//username
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kullaniciSifre", sifre);  //password
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int UserExist = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (UserExist > 1)
            {
                //if given there is a user with given username and password?? 
                // i don't know how to do that first should i check username and then check that username's password or what?? 
                //successful
            }
            else
            {
                //wrong password or username
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SoapException se)
        {
            throw se;
        }
    }
```

and here is mine aspx page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnLogin').click(login);
    });
    function login() {
        var kullaniciAd = $('#userName').val();
        var sifre = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:63000/LoginService.asmx/Login",
            type: "POST", //or should it be GET? 
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ kullaniciAd: kullaniciAd, sifre: sifre }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=windows-1254",
            success: function () {
                alert("");// i have an alert div down there how can i show  if login is successful or not in that alert div
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e.statusText);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
<%--<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <button contenteditable="false" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
              aria-hidden="true">
              ×</button>
              <strong>Well done!</strong>You successfully read this important alert message.
</div>--%>
```

it seems so easy but i can't decide if i check true or false in web service and just send jquery just one data(true, false) or check if true or false in jquery with calling true or false web method ??

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I've seen login logic that checks if there is ANY user that matches the entered password. My advice.. don't.

A better way would be to check if the user with the given userid exists and then return the stored password(and salt) from the data store.The next step would be to hash the entered plain password and check it with the stored value. This gives you three possible outcomes

- The user is known but the password entered was incorrect
- The user is not found(the sql query returned 0 results)
- The user was found and the password was correct

The only choice you need to make is whether or not you want to report the difference between the first two cases. Some would consider it a security issue because it could be use for phising.. you can find out what user are registered at your system, so many system would simply report, "user / password combination incorrect"

Some more information on using hashing to secure your password storage
https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm